# Toggle buttons that control visibility of other groups and controls

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx, ribbon-control

I am trying to include toggle buttons (4) that will toggle groups visible or invisible through tags while also making the other toggle buttons invisible. The reset will make all groups invisible, except for toggle group

The code works without including the toggle buttons.

Toggle 1 controls groups 1 and 5.
Toggle 2 controls groups 2 and 6.
Toggle 3 controls groups 3 and 7.
Toggle 4 controls groups 4 and 8.

I've pared it down for confidentiality.
Unfortunately, the ribbon doesn't load.

This is my current xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI onLoad="OnStart" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <!-- New tab -->
            <tab id="tab1" label="tab1" insertBeforeMso="TabHome">

                <!-- New group - toggle buttons that controls other groups -->
                <group id="GroupToggle" label="Toggle">
                    <toggleButton id="Toggle1" label="Toggle 1" size="large" onAction="onActionToggle" imageMso="_1" tag="Toggle1Main" getVisible="GetVisible" />
                    <toggleButton id="Toggle2" label="Toggle 2" size="large" onAction="onActionToggle" imageMso="_2" tag="Toggle2Main" getVisible="GetVisible" />
                    <toggleButton id="Toggle3" label="Toggle 3" size="large" onAction="onActionToggle" imageMso="_3" tag="Toggle3Main" getVisible="GetVisible" />
                    <toggleButton id="Toggle4" label="Toggle 4" size="large" onAction="onActionToggle" imageMso="_4" tag="Toggle4Main" getVisible="GetVisible" />
                    
                    <!-- This option is always visible -->
                    <button id="ToggleReset" label="Reset" size="large" onAction="onActionToggle" imageMso="R" tag="ToggleMain" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle1 -->
                <group id="group1" label="Group 1" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle1">
                    <button id="group1btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle2 -->
                <group id="group2" label="Group 2" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle2">
                    <button id="group2btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 3 -->
                <group id="group3" label="Group 3" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle3">
                    <button id="group3btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 4 -->
                <group id="group4" label="Group 4" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle4">
                    <button id="group4btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 1 -->
                <group id="group5" label="Group 5" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle1">
                    <button id="group5btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 2 -->
                <group id="group6" label="Group 6" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle2">
                    <button id="group6btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 3 -->
                <group id="group7" label="Group 7" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle3">
                    <button id="group7btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>

                <!-- Toggle with Toggle 4 -->
                <group id="group8" label="Group 8" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="Toggle4">
                    <button id="group8btn1" label="btn 1" onAction="onActionBtn1" imageMso="A" />
                </group>


            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

This is my current vba

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ribbon As IRibbonControl
Public MyTag As String

Sub OnStart(ribbon As IRibbonControl)
  Set Ribbon = ribbon
  Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="*Main")
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
  MyTag = Tag
  If Ribbon Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error. Reload"
  Else
    Ribbon.Invalidate
  End If
End Sub

Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
  If MyTag = "show" Then
    visible = True
  Else
    If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
      visible = True
    Else
      visible = False
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub onActionToggle(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
  Select Case control.ID
    Case "Toggle1"
      Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle1*")
    Case "Toggle2"
      Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle2*")
    Case "Toggle3"
      Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle3*")
    Case "Toggle4"
      Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle4*")
    Case "Toggle4"
      Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="*Main")
  End Select
End Sub

Sub onActionBtn1(control As IRibbonControl)
  Select Case control.ID
    Case "group1btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group2btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group3btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group4btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group5btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group6btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group7btn1"
      'Runs code
    Case "group8btn1"
      'Runs code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there are several errors going on here, some more important than others. These changes were all needed to make your code run:

- No `End Select` in `onActionBtn1`.
- Wrong signature for `On Start`, must be `Sub OnStart(ribbon As IRibbonUI)`.
- Wrong type for `Ribbon` variable, must be `IRibbonUI`.
- Wrong name for `Ribbon` variable - must have different name than `ribbon` parameter of the `OnStart`-callback, e.g. `MyRibbon`.
- Reset-button is `<button>` but `onAction` points to `onActionToggle` used for a `<toggleButton>` - must point to `onActionBtn1` or similar.
- You refer to the Reset-button by its Tag name `ToggleMain`, but the Id is `ToggleReset`.
- Also made your variables private, should be as restrictive as possible.

Putting it all together to make you code work:

**XML**

Change `onAction` for `ToggleReset` to point to `"onActionBtn1"`

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Private MyRibbon As IRibbonUI
Private MyTag As String

Sub OnStart(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  Set MyRibbon = ribbon
  Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="*Main")
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
  MyTag = Tag
  If MyRibbon Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Error. Reload"
  Else
     MyRibbon.Invalidate
  End If
End Sub

Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
  If MyTag = "show" Then
     visible = True
  Else
     If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
        visible = True
     Else
        visible = False
     End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub onActionToggle(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
  Select Case control.ID
     Case "Toggle1"
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle1*")
     Case "Toggle2"
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle2*")
     Case "Toggle3"
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle3*")
     Case "Toggle4"
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="Toggle4*")
  End Select
End Sub

Sub onActionBtn1(control As IRibbonControl)
  Select Case control.ID
     Case "group1btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group2btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group3btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group4btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group5btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group6btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group7btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "group8btn1"
        'Runs code
     Case "ToggleReset"
        Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="*Main")
  End Select
End Sub
```